# Being forced in past and future

Tags: grammar, tense

Today (Sunday):

P1: "Let's go to the cinema"

P2: "Oh! sorry. I had to go home"

Tomorrow (Monday):

P3: "Did you go to the cinema yesterday?"

P2: "My friend invited me, but ..."

How should I express being forced in the past? Should I say "but I did had to go home" or "but I was had to go home" or what?

What about being forced at the future?

P1: "Will you go to the cinema tomorrow?"

P2: "I want to go, but I ..."

Is this correct? "but I will had to go somewhere"

Comment: Why did your friend say "I **had** to go home"? That's very odd: it implies that at that time the obligation to go home lay in the past, before the invitation and before the screening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically*, P2 does not directly respond to P1. There is some implied extra meaning hidden in P2's first sentence. When P2 says "Sorry. I had to go home", they mean "Sorry. I had to go home, so I will not be able to go to the cinema."

---

(I am assuming you meant P2 in the second group of sentences where you have P1.)

The second group would turn out something like:

> P3: Did you go to the cinema yesterday?
>
> P2: My friend invited me, but I had to go home.

It's the same conjugation ("had"). Why? Because both sentences are referring to the past — in both cases, P2 has already had to go home before they speak. Therefore both sentences can use the same conjugation.

---

For the third pair of sentences, you could complete them with:

> P1: Will you go to the cinema tomorrow?
>
> P2: I want to go, but I have to go somewhere else instead.

"Have" refers to the future here; "I have to go somewhere" means "In the future, I will be moving to a different place that prevents me from going to the cinema with you."

If you want, you could also write:

> P2: I want to go, but I will have to go somewhere.

This indicates more strongly that P2 will be leaving for "somewhere" at an indiscriminate point in the future. (Note that not specifying a specific location here would be seen by a native English speaker as P2 rudely attempting to get out of going to the cinema with P1.)

Comment: Thank you for reply! But how can I know the tense of the sentence if it was alone? I mean, what is the meaning of this sentence? "I had to go home." This means "I had to go home **now**" or "I had to go home **yesterday**"?

Comment: @lucas "I had to go home" effectively means "I had to go home **before right now.**" The verb "had" in this case is simple past tense: it means that the action it describes ("to go home", in this case) was done before the moment the sentence was uttered.

Comment: @lucas If you wanted to say that the speaker is required to leave now (and not before), they would say "I **have** to go home now" (instead of "had").